# a problem with calling API from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which make a content script, I'm trying to make an API call, but I can't get the response.
I'm getting response with type CORS and status 200.
I already attached the external API host to the permissions section at the manifest.json

my code is:

```
fetch('http://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/ip-address/report?ip=8.8.8.8&apikey=My API KEY')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
// Response{type: cors, url:http://www.virustotal.com/....... status: 200}
        return res.json(); // Here is the problem
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "IP information on hover",
    "description": "IP information on hover",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "https://www.virustotal.com/",
        "http://www.virustotal.com/"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery-3.4.0.js",
                "getIpReport.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at getIpReport.js:23

Comment: When you paste the virustotal URL in your address bar, do you see a valid JSON response? For instance if I try this without API key, the response is blank. This would cause the error you describe.

Comment: Content scripts can't make cross-origin requests [anymore](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches), do it in the background script.

Comment: Chris G, yes it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content scripts can't make cross-origin requests anymore, do it in the background script 
thank you wOxxOm